# how to properly define scopes in Datamapper

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

Is there an ability to define scopes similar to Rails `ActiveRecord` way?

Answer (score 0):

http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html

```
class Zoo
  # all the keys and property setup here
  def self.open
    all(:open => true)
  end

  def self.big
    all(:animal_count => 1000)
  end
end

big_open_zoos = Zoo.big.open
```

So nothing special about scopes, just ruby.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to Datamapper.
One more question: For example I have a Table and I need to fetch certain column1 by parameters of Column2.
by your's method I will get array of objects, but is there a way to get array of certain values. (I mean is there way to perform a "lighter" query not to fetch unnecessary data)